# Why Haskell's list not made as an instance of State Monad?

Tags: haskell

I read some Haskell's Stack and Queen sample code(like this: https://rafal.io/posts/haskell-queues.html). They make Stack and Queen as instance of State Monad to make it easy to use.

So can Haskell's list be make as instance of State Monad?

But if not, why? It seems insert into a list

```
1:[2,3,4]
```

like push 1 in stack. So

1. Can list be made as instance of State Monad?
2. If it can, why doesn't Haskell make it as instance of State Monad? I think because it's the most used data structure, so if make it as instance of State Monad, it's hard to use (compare with use it directly)

Comment: Could you maybe link the sample code you're referring to?

Comment: @oisdk I think it's about section 04: "Adding the State Monad / We can finally wrap our Queue into the State monad for easier chaining of operations." - I guess OP read that as making the Queue there an instance of said monad

Comment: I think you get the idea that the queue in the state monad is somehow easier to use than just the queue - I'd argue this is wrong - this monad does not magically turn Haskell into an imperative language - you have to push anything you'll want to do into the state-monad context to work this way - this might be easier or it might be just more boilerplate depending on your situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Wagner points out, any data structure can be used as the state in the State monad, including lists.

> can list be make as instance of State Monad?

The use of the word *instance* implies that perhaps you consider the state monad a *type class*. It's not (but read on). *State* is a specific instance of `Monad`, just like `[]` (list) is, and just like `Maybe` and `Either l` are instances of `Monad`.

That said, I admit that things are somewhat confusing, because [there *is* a type class called `MonadState`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html). If you look at the instances, however, you'll see that most of them are self-referential. Only two 'leaf' instances are defined, `StateT` (from which `State` is defined) and the exotic `RWST`.

If you consider `State`, you'll see that it's always a `Monad`. For `StateT`:

```
Monad m => Monad (StateT s m)
```

Since `State` is defined as:

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

and `Identity` is unconditionally a `Monad` instance, you get that `State s` is always a `Monad`, regardless of what `s` is.

That's what Daniel Wagner points out. Specifically, `State [Int]`, `State [Char]`, `State [Bool]`, etc. are all `Monad` instances. It's a family of monads.

Comment: FTR, there's nothing very _exotic_ about `RWST`, it's just a pre-made equivalent to a stack of the `Reader`, `Writer` and `State` transformers.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I mean *exotic* in the sense that it's rarely seen, but I could be mistaken. While I've never seen it anywhere else, I'm only a sample of one. Do you see it used outside of the `Control.Monad.State` module (and submodules)?

Comment: "*State* is a specific instance of `Monad`" -- you might find ['The' reader monad does not exist](https://blog.plover.com/prog/haskell/the-reader-monad.html) amusing (I did).

Comment: I think `RWST` might be more common in application code than library code.

Answer (score 3):

The `State` family of monads can use any data structure, big or small, as its state, including lists -- there is one monad in the family for each structure.